# Android WebView Not Responding to flash plugin in the website

Tags: android, flash, webview

I have a andriod application with webView. The website which is loading contain a jquery plugin zviewer to load pdf. But the app not responding to the pdf files.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved using the following code, which allowed me to open supported application to view the pdf file.

```
webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i); 
    }
});
```